Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in

Error - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in blog.class.php on line 31

What is the reason, please tell me? PHP 7.1
I've tried different options, but I'm not good at PHP.
public function route()
{
    $res = bff::route(array(
            'blog/(.*)\-([\d]+)'     => 'blog/view/id=$2',
            'blog/tag/(.*)\-([\d]+)' => 'blog/listingTag/tag=$2',
            'blog/(page\d+\/?)'      => 'blog/listing/page=$1',
            'blog/(.*)'              => 'blog/listing/cat=$1',
    ), true
    );

    if ($res['event'] === false || !method_exists($this, $res['event'])) {
        $res['event'] = 'listing';
    }

    return $this->$res['event']() ;
}


Which line is line 31? Is it return $this->$res['event']()?

Yes, it is return $this->$res'event' ;

You probably want to make sure that $res['event'] is a string instead of false. Apparently method_exists will still work if true is passed as the second parameter , though it's returning as false so it should still reassign event. - https://3v4l.org/JFQ5A

What is bff? It might be a good idea to start there if it is an open source library, maybe this is already solved or documented. "I'm not good at PHP" - with all due respect, you’ve got RegEx, variable variables ($this->$res) and dynamic function invocation, that’s a lot going on for someone not comfortable with the language

And how to solve this problem? I can give you the full code

Use call_user_func().

The  problem is that
$this->$res['event']()

is parsed as
($this->$res)['event']()

So it expects $this->$res to be an array of functions.
But based on the earlier code, it looks like $res['event'] is supposed to be the name of a method. So you need to override this default grouping. To use an expression as a dynamic method or property name, put it in {}.
return $this->{$res['event']}();

